# mysql-connector-python loop over cursors very slow

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I am not able to query a mysql database using mysql-connector-python (python version 3.5).  I am trying to pull out air_temperature for a particular datetime range for an entire list of stations.  The first query for the first stn works just fine, but the 2nd just hangs forever.

```
import mysql.connector
import datetime

connection = mysql.connector.connect(host=' ', 
                       user=' ', 
                       passwd=' ', 
                       database=' ', 
                       port= ) 

stn_id = [‘stn_01’,’stn_02’, ’stn_03’, ’stn_04’, ’stn_05’]
datetime_start = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1, 00, 00, 00)
datetime_end   = datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 1, 00, 00, 00)

for stn in range(0,n_stn,1): 
    cursor = connection.cursor(buffered=True)

    q = """
            SELECT time_stamp, air_temperature
            FROM %s
            WHERE time_stamp >= %s
            AND   time_stamp <= %s
        """

    cursor.execute(q,(stn_id[stn], datetime_start, datetime_end))
    temp_results = cursor.fetchall()
    # do something with the results 
    cursor.close()
```

Comment: try moving the line `cursor = connection.cursor(buffered=True)` outside of the for loop. Also, it would be more pythonic to use you loop as `for stn in stn_id`